# Sass, marking a variable as a string

Tags: variables, sass

I'm trying to run a loop in Sass to generate the following variables:

```
$size-xs: 1em;
$size-sm: 1.1em;
$size-md: 1.2em;
$size-lg: 1.3em;
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$size-base:1em;
$size-increment:0.1em;

$size-list: "xs","sm","md","lg";

@each $value-size in $size-list {
    $size-#{$value-size}:#{$i};
    $i:$size-base + $size-increment;
}
```

The problems I'm having is the $size- is interpreted as a variable, but it's not, it's the root of a set of variables I'd like to generate.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: What is the expected CSS output?

Comment: so for this there actually is no css out put, I'm trying to generate the list of variables I first mention.  These variables are used later in CSS classes.

Comment: Well you can't create new variables dynamically. But I am wondering, why not just make the value of the variable dynamic? You already have the prefix's hard coded and I am assuming only the values would change.

Comment: Also you may find this of help.. http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Two-handy-and-advanced-SASS-features-and-their-limitations

Answer (score 0):

The error you were getting was because variable names can't be interpolated like that. (You were also trying to use `$i` before it was defined.)

But you can directly name the elements that will be styled. For example:

```
$size-base: 1em;
$size-increment: 0.1em;
$size-list: "xs", "sm", "md", "lg";

@each $value-size in $size-list {
  $size-base: $size-base + $size-increment;
  .#{$value-size} {
    font-size: $size-base;
  }
}
```

You can even just output silent placeholders instead of elements, and then extend them when needed.

```
$size-base: 1em;
$size-increment: 0.1em;
$size-list: "%xs", "%sm", "%md", "%lg";

@each $value-size in $size-list {
  $size-base: $size-base + $size-increment;
  #{$value-size} {
    font-size: $size-base;
  }
}

h2 {
  @extend %lg;
}
```

This will only compile the h2 style declaration.

See the example at http://sassmeister.com/gist/a400ded59756a814c47e.

Comment: Do you *ever* vote to close questions as duplicates?  Nevermind the fact that this question is an obvious duplicate, but this is an extremely poor solution.  You're either recommending extending these classes (which leads to code bloat) or polluting the markup with presentational classes.

Comment: @cimmanon - Please don't target other users with hostile comments like this. They are free to provide good answers to whatever questions they want, and may not agree with your assessment that this is a duplicate.